# Trying to setup a mail server on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server, mysql, thunderbird, postfix, dovecot

I'm trying to set up a mail server but get the following errors whilst trying to connect with thunderbird:

```
Jan  7 03:11:59 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[6752]: lost connection after CONNECT from xxx
Jan  7 03:11:59 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal postfix/smtpd[6752]: disconnect from xxx
```

and

```
Jan  7 03:11:59 Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal dovecot: imap-login: Disconnected (no auth attempts in 0 secs): user=<>, rip=xxx, lip=xxx, TLS: SSL_read() failed: error:14094418:SSL routine$
```

I'm using dovecot, postfix and mysql for the mail server. The certificates are self signed and are in the location stated in dovecot.conf, but still no connection. Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like something goes wrong with SSL connection setup. In effect there's no proper authentication done and disconnection.

Maybe verify your Thunderbird settings related to encryption? Have you accepted the self-signed certificate in Thunderbird when connecting?